# Creating a VIEW from multiple tables each with a different number of columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to combine multiple tables into one `VIEW`.
My understanding is that if the number of columns are different we cannot use `UNION`.
How do I solve this?

I have the following three `TABLES`:

1.**Table Name- Albums**

[image]

2.**Table Name-AlbumPictures**

[image]

3.**Table Name-Stories**

[image]

I want to have 3 tables as follows:(i can do this part using INNER JOINS- kindly correct me if i am wrong)

**For Stories:** StoryID,AlbumID,StoryTitle,AlbumCover,Votes

**For Albums:** AlbumID,AlbumName,AlbumCover,Votes

**For Pictures:** AlbumPictureID,Votes

I want to merge all the rows retrieved from the above queries into one `VIEW`and shuffle them. As the number of columns are different in each of the result sets above am I able to combine them into one `VIEW`?

Comment: What columns do you want in the view?  In SQL, views and tables have fixed and pre-defined columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have mentioned it in the Question Under For Stories,For Albums & For Pictures

Comment: How can it be possible? You want to create three different tables of different structures and merge them into a view???

Comment: @user1593175 . . . You have three different lists of columns.  For a view, you can have only one list.  Do you want all those fields in the view?

Comment: It is not possible to bring three different result sets in a single view. Not sure your requirement. If you tell us your requirement, there may be an alternative approach.

Comment: @kaf In the UI i am retrieving the data on scroll...so i need to have all the data in the same View..correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Chad In the UI i am retrieving the data on scroll...so i need to have all the data in the same View..correct me if i am wrong...on a scroll i retrieve 10 rows from the View..also i have to display 3 types of data ie. Albums,Pictures and Stories...so i have different columns.

Comment: Are you showing them on a data bound control like Grid?

Comment: @Chad I am using Jquery for ajax call to the DB to retrieve n number of rows on each scroll.

Comment: @kaf Nope, plain html and jQuery.

Comment: Rework your question.  Explain clearly what it is you are trying to accomplish.  That is the best advice I can give you.  Your question is asking the wrong thing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. *`All three tables are given similar columns with null values`* and *`TableName column is to identify the table which brings the data`*

**EDIT:** *I have to say, this is not the right approach. I wanted to show you how to union tables but I think now it is getting ugly when editing it according to your comments.*

```
--Note: Vote is on all three table, I have selected from Stories
select s.storyId, a.albumId, s.storyTitle, null albumName, 
       ap.albumCover, s.votes , null albumPictureId, 'stories-albums-albumPics' tableName
from Stories s join Albums a on s.albumId = a.albumId 
               join AlbumPictures ap on a.albumid = ap.albumId

UNION ALL 
select null storyId, a.albumID, null storyTitle, a.albumName,
       ap.albumCover, a.votes, null albumPictureId, 'albums-albumPics' tableName
from Albums a join AlbumPictures ap on a.albumid = ap.albumId

UNION ALL --use required table here as well  
select null storyId, null albumId, null storyTitle, null albumName, 
       null albumCover, votes, albumPictureId, 'pictures' tableName 
from Pictures
```

Comment: For the 1st SELECT AlbumCover comes from the AlbumPictures table.So, do i have to use a INNER JOIN HERE?And it cannot be null as i need it.

Comment: @user1593175 : Yeah, this is the idea, I am sure you can implement as required.

Comment: Sorry i am getting confused here, can you please add the query to your answer?

Comment: Will it be something like this? `SELECT        StoryID, AlbumID, StoryTitle, NULL AS albumName, (select url from AlbumPictures where AlbumID=Stories.AlbumID and AlbumCover='True'), Votes, NULL AS PictureId, 'stories' AS tableName
FROM            dbo.Stories
`

Comment: I have to say, this is not the right approach. I wanted to show you how to union tables but I think now it is getting ugly with more details to the original question.

Comment: What would be your suggestion then?

Comment: Does `UNION ALL` give me duplicate Data? Or Should i use `UNION`?

Comment: I think you have to explain your problem with much details rather than asking how to do this. Coz there may be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes `UNION ALL` gives duplicates.

Comment: In the UI i am retrieving the data on scroll...so i need to have all the data in the same View..correct me if i am wrong...on a scroll i retrieve 10 rows from the View..also i have to display 3 types of data ie. Albums,Pictures and Stories...so i have different columns.

Comment: What i mean here is that on every scroll i bring 10 rows of data from the View.It is similar to paging.Rather than clicking on the page number i use scroll.Hope am making sense.

Answer (score 7):

So in your UNION sql, either remove the extra columns from the sql for the table with too many,  or add extra columns with constant default values to the sql for the table with fewer columns.

Based on your example output, adding extra constant values might look like this...

```
Select StoryID id, AlbumID, 
    StoryTitle name, AlbumCover, Votes
From Stories
 UNION
Select AlbumID id, AlbumID, 
     AlbumName name, AlbumCover, Votes
From Albums
   UNION
Select AlbumPictureID id, null AlbumId, 
     null AlbumCover, Votes
From pictures
Order By id, Votes, name
```

But this makes me want to ask WHY???

EDIT: To sort, just add an order by using output column names, as shown above....

Comment: yeah Why :P. it doesnt make any sense to have story id,album id and picture id in a column..

Comment: In the UI i am retrieving the data on scroll...so i need to have all the data in the same View..correct me if i am wrong...is there any way i can sort the rows within the View.

Comment: yeah then in the UI how will you identify Story_Id and Album Id??

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operator, the number of columns and datatypes of the columns returned by each query have to be the same.

One trick you can use is to return a NULL value for the columns that are "missing" from some of the queries.

For performance, I recommend you use the `UNION ALL` operator in place of the `UNION` operator, if removing duplicates is not a requirement.

Whenever I need to do something like this, I usually include a literal in each query, as an identifier of which query the row came from.

e.g.

```
SELECT 'a'     AS source
     , a.id    AS id
     , a.name  AS name 
  FROM table_a a
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b'     AS source
     , b.id    AS id
     , NULL    AS name
  FROM table_b b
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this makes little sense,

```
Select StoryID+'SID' id, AlbumID, 
    StoryTitle name, AlbumCover, Votes
From Stories
 UNION
Select AlbumID+'AID' id, AlbumID, 
     AlbumName name, AlbumCover, Votes
From Albums
   UNION
Select AlbumPictureID+'APID' id, null AlbumId, 
     null AlbumCover, Votes
From pictures
```

Concatenating 'SID','AID' and 'APID' and it will make some sense when you see UI data

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Stories as s
inner join Albums as a on a.AccountID = s.AccountID
inner join Pictures as p on p.AccountID = s.AccountID
```

will return all, as long as `AccountID` is defined in all 3 tables

To only obtain the unique columns change * for the columns you desire

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and hit the `{}` code button - it retains the formatting and adds syntax highlighting.

Comment: and how would i understand...which row is from which table?

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you need the data to be all in the same view? Just return 3 sets of data. If for example you are using a web browser as the front end, you could perform three queries and return them as a single set of JSON, for example:

```
{
   Albums: [
      {AlbumID: 1, AlbumName: 'blah', ... },
      {AlbumID: 2, AlbumName: 'gorp', ... } 
   ],
   AlbumPictures: [
      {AlbumID: 1, URL: 'http://fun.jpg'},
      {AlbumID: 1, URL: 'http://fun2.jpg'}
   ],
   Stories [
      {StoryID: 3, StoryTitle: 'Jack & Jill', ... },
      { etc. }
   ]
}
```

There is absolutely no programming architectural constraint forcing you to put everything together in a single view.

Comment: You understood my problem, i am sure your solution is the best..can you give me a brief example, how can i create a JSON object like you did in your answer? I am confused how will i distinguish which is `Albums` or `AlbumPictures` or `Stories` and can i sort the data too in the JSON object?

Comment: What language are you querying the database from? What kind of GUI do the users have? Is it a browser? We know almost nothing about what you are doing and thus cannot help very much.

Comment: Yes the UI is a browser, i am using ASP.NET web forms with sql server.

Comment: So the problem is not with SELECTing from the database. It's either with your C#/VB.Net code (creating JSON from it), or with your javascript code (if you're using Ajax). You need to open a new question. Do not show your table layout--that's irrelevant. The real question you need to get answered is how to send three recordsets to the client using ASP.Net. Go off and ask that question, **WITH what you've tried** or at least what you have so far, and give me a link here.